# Как из одной вьюхи передать данные сразу в 2 контроллера?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеются модели `book` и `author`.

Во вьюхе `books/new` поля для ввода названия книги и имени автора.

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "добавить книгу", создавался и объект книги, и объект автора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим это ваша модель

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :author

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
# ^^^ эта строчка нужна, что бы автор создавался автоматически
end
```

это ваш view

```
<%= form_for @book, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= fields_for @book.author do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

тогда в котроллере

```
book = Book.create(params[:book])
```